# Providing REST API over Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

As far as it goes to standard clients, be it web, mobile, etc. the path to authentication is clear and simple. Firebase provides this facility out of the box.

However, when it comes to exposing a platform through REST API, what would is the way to go?

If Firebase supports, I could not find anything thus far online about it.

Has anyone in this community implemented something similar on top of Firebase?

Comment: At this link provided enough information I think. Hope hepls https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

Comment: @HakanC - how come I missed it?  :-).